# How to speed up application publishing to Weblogic from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am using *Eclipse Kepler* with *Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12.1.2.3* and a *Weblogic 12.1.1*. When starting the server with an added EAR project from Eclipse the starting stops at

```
Publishing to Oracle Weblogic Server 12c (12.1.1.) at localhost [project] (3%)
```

After a minute or so it continues.

What is Weblogic doing? The Eclipse process view says *Checking for deployed modules*.

Is there any way to speed up the publishing process?

Comment: If you remove eclipse from the situation and install your EAR manually how long does it take? There's probably not going to be a solution to your question...

Comment: Using Maven from command line (`mvn com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:deploy`) seems to be eben slower. I will now check the deployment via _Weblogic Console_.